# Python-admin grappeli - missing Action drop down for delete (or other actions)

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I'm toying with [Grappeli](http://grappelliproject.com/) for my django admin. After following the setup instructions I can't find the **action** dropdown. allowing me for example to remove an object.  which makes it unusable. any Ideas? clues to what am I doing wrong?

I'm using (inherited from another programmer) django-storage with s3 as the storage
and set:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'server.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'server.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'

Note that while doing collect static - after the grappeli part. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 173, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 101, in collect
    for finder in finders.get_finders():
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 253, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 32, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 265, in _get_finder
    return Finder()
  File "/home/alon/.virtualenvs/stox-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 62, in __init__
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

But since the rest of the grappelli look and feel is there. I'm not sure if this problem is connected at all

Answer (score 4):

The action drop down is all the way at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Whelp, I'm blind. This helped me